# How to access php Ini in cpanel

Tags: php

i can not find the **php Ini** in cpanel where is it? and where i can create custom php ini to change some default configuration like max_upload_size.
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Main >> Service Configuration >> PHP Configuration Editor

Have a look here : http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/PhpIni

Answer (score 0):

You can find the location by using `php_ini_loaded_file();` in a php script.
But you should know that can set the max upload size in your php file itself, no need to edit the php.ini file

```
ini_set('max_upload_size', '64M');
```

Answer (score 0):

May be its different but it is helpful instead of changing in ini file  write this

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '96M');
```

maximum file upload size is 2M you can give your limit in 96..hope this help full

Answer (score 0):

> You can go directly by clicking wamp tray icon as shown in below. In
>   this case, you have to run wamp se[image]rver

and find upload_max_filesize and you can change the it.and save the php.ini file than restart wamp server